# Firebase Javascript Ajax & Session Issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, firebase, session

I have an issue to create session or make ajax request in Javascript. Actually I am using firebase Facebook Oauth and I want when login success via facebook it save all data in a session a key and However and redirect to `'./fetchedata.php'` at `'./fetchedata.php'` I will call the session and echo the data which was saved in key.

I dont know I do this, I know Jquery and I will do that same if Firebase was in Qjuery but I dont know well Javascript Ajx.

Please help to me create Session and Atlest Ajax in Javascript so I learn with my code.

Thank You.
**HTML**

```
<!--If Login Session true thenn redirect to ./fetchedata.php else stay on this page.-->
<button onclick="signin()" id="sign-in">Sign in with Facebook</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var firebaseConfig = {..}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function signin() {
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user_birthday,email');
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.

      //Session Start Store all the data in KEY//
      //Session Name = "Login Status"
      //Start Redirct to ./fetchedata.php
      document.querySelector("#sign-out").style.display = "block";
      console.log(user);
      var user = result.user;
      console.log(user.email);
      // ...
      //Session END//
   }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
   });

}
```

Comment: Why are you using firebase if you want to redirect with PHP?

Comment: I can use php instead firebase, but It simple to integration and use. Is possible to to as I posted ?